# How to kill all processes in one virtual console from another virtual console?

Tags: virtual-console

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F(1-6)</kbd>, I'm directed to virtual terminal. I've two user account except guest. When I try to login from one of those two users, my system gets hang. So, I was wondering how to restart that virtual console from another virtual console or how to kill all processes in one virtual console from another virtual console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
ps -ft tty2
```

Output will be look like:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1024     1  0 06:52 tty2     00:00:00 /bin/login --     
gulu      3532  1024  0 09:15 tty2     00:00:00 -bash
```

Here I am going to kill Virtual Console 2 (`tty2`). Just kill the pid of `/bin/login --` with `root` privilege

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

here,

```
kill -9 1024
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have sufficient privileges, you can use `pkill` with the `-t` switch to kill all processes on a particular terminal device e.g. to kill all processes under the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> virtual terminal (whose device is `/dev/tty2`)

```
sudo pkill -t tty2
```

See `man pkill` for additional options